# Azure DevOps build pipeline corrupts unicode filenames

Tags: unicode, msbuild, azure-pipelines, filenames, visual-studio-2022

We have a legacy .NET MVC 5 project targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2. We've created a build pipeline in Azure Devops using Classic interface (we will switch to YAML later), and we have a hosted agent pool with a single hosted agent. The pipeline specifies to use "windows-latest".

Our problem is that the `App_Data` folder contains a couple of files with non ascii characters, and in the built image these file names are corrupted. As an example. the original file name `PuBavtalRegistervård.pdf` ends up as `PuBavtalRegisterv├Ñrd.pdf`. If you take the latter as an OEM850 encoded string and interpret it as UTF-8 then you get the original file name. So it would appear that somewhere along the way the file names that are originally in unicode get correctly encoded as UTF-8 but then that string is interpreted as if it were OEM850 and published as such into the built image.

This problem does not occur when we build from within Visual Studio (2022). In VS, both regular build (F5) and publish (to file system) work just fine.

The pipeline uses this MSBuild command line:

`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"`

Is there any way we can get it to handle these file names correctly?

Comment: From the command line that you shared, it seems that MSBuild is performing the copies of the files. Is the build in the build pipeline using the same version of MSBuild? Is the agent host configured with the VS2022 build tools?

Comment: For the build task, "Visual Studio Version" is set to "Latest" (and in the dropdown, the latest seems to be VS 2022). I see no option to control the version of MSBuild to use. how can I check and/or control this?

Comment: @KjellRilbe Hi, I posted an answer, Please try whether self host agent is able to avoid this issue. It can use the same configuration as local. And if possible, could you please share detailed reproduce steps? :)

Comment: @KjellRilbe What kind of agent are you using? [Self-hosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops)? [Microsoft-hosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)?

Comment: @JonathanDodds Hosted as far as I know. The agent pool has a cloud icon and Owner appears as "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS". For sure we don't have any server configured for this purpose, neither physical nor in the Azure cloud.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT Our local machines are Windows 11 Pro with Swedish locale (Windows-1252 I presume). I see no way to specify the locale for the hosted agent. That said, at this time I would assume all tools etc. to use unicode. Appears to not be the case here. The PDF is a simple content file under the App_Data folder. Not sure what steps I should provide... csproj? pubxml? pipeline yml?

Comment: For info: I have currently implemented a work-around consisting of a PowerShell task at the end of the release job, which renames affected files (using pattern for each of the corrupted characters). Not sure I will be able to invest much time in further effort to resolve the underlying problem at this time.

Comment: @KjellRilbe Because it is a Microsoft hosted agent, I would open an issue with Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to confirm, in your case, the pdf file is used as part of the build but you encounter an error when building? Similar to copy file to bin?

Please describe the specific steps to reproduce the problem more clearly.

---

I think the problem may be related to the machine.

I noticed you mentioned "windows-latest" and "This problem does not occur when we build from within Visual Studio (2022). In VS, both regular build (F5) and publish (to file system) work just fine." , so you encounter errors on a randomly assigned Windows machine, but you can succeed on the Windows machine where you test locally, right?

If so, one possible solution is to use a self host agent. This technology ensures that the environment your pipeline runs in is consistent with the local machine.

You can refer to this document:

[Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#install)

[Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops)

This technique should be feasible in your situation, it can make sure the consistence. And even if you don't pay, as long as you use self host agent, you can have free unlimited running time in private projects. The machine of ms host agent is completely random. If it is self host agent, the environment can be pre-configured.

[image]

By the way, you also can use pipeline task to change the name of the files.

Comment: I see. Well, that would be an option I suppose, if the actual underlying problem can't be resolved.

Comment: @KjellRilbe Hi Kjell, any update on this? If this answer could be a solution to solve the issue, could you please [mark it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? If you find a better answer, you can mark that answer as answer instead. This will be beneficial for others who encounter the similar issue and seeking for the solution. :)

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment above I've implemented a workaround, so I'm afraid I won't have time to investigate this further at the moment. Hopefully I will be able to get back to it at some point, but don't hold your breath. Really sorry about this, but there's not much I can do about it.